# Symfony - swagger ui can not load from path

Tags: php, symfony, swagger, swagger-ui

I am trying to run static html page within Swagger documentation. I am at Symfony version 5.

I have installed [zircote/swagger-php](https://github.com/zircote/swagger-php) library.

Second thing I did is that I have downloaded swagger ui and put everything inside `/public/` folder path like this:

[image].

I changed url in Swagger UI `index.html` like:

```
  url: window.location.protocol + "//" + window.location.hostname + ":" + window.location.port + "/resources/documentation/api/api.php",
```

and in api.php file:

```
<?php
require("vendor/autoload.php");
$openapi = \OpenApi\Generator::scan([__DIR__ . '/../../src/Controller/Api']);
header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo $openapi->toJson();
```

When I run the view I get:

[image]

But as I can see in the browser everything is loaded correctly regarding the path so I do not know here the problem is.

As you can see I have added path for `scan` method in `api.php` where I am location Controller folder with classes where are methods that are defined by Annotations.. So they should be loaded?

Can someone help?

Comment: The `.../api/api.php` file name doesn't look right. The generated API definition file would most likely be `.yaml`, `.yml`, `.json` or have no file extension.

Comment: That is the file that load the location where Annotations of specific endpoints are defined. Check this link : https://medium.com/@tatianaensslin/how-to-add-swagger-ui-to-php-server-code-f1610c01dc03 @Helen

Comment: That guide uses `url: window.location.protocol + "//" + window.location.hostname + "/path-to-your-swagger.json",` - note the file is JSON, not PHP. See also "Step 3: Generate your swagger.json (or swagger.yaml)!"

Comment: Yes, but as you can see in my api.php file, I am scanning directory which contains open api annotations for some of the defined endpoints in specific controller. @Helen